# How to recover a embedded CE mobile device bricked after OS update

Tags: embedded, windows-ce, windows-embedded-compact, omap

My question is how to set the codes below so we can send file to the unit, we have the file in Hex format, I don't understand the level of coding to make the file send, is this a command coding or not.

Update OS dated to the MC92N0 with Image v04.57.04.
now unit is blank, reboot power light flash once.
can connect to hyperterminal but only get those commands?

```
rxx Read reg xx
wxxdd White dd to reg xx    
d Toggle debug msge    
v version    
f Free RAM    
p Port valuse    
t,+,-,l TC LED    
<,> Batt Temp    
a Assert WR    
s Start WB    
q Reset debug
```

Question is how to reload files? to bring it back?

On a working unit.
The software is loaded to a Emmc chip, OMAP4430 ES 2.3 by RS232 interface.
when the device is working correctly the system has partition as below.

```
0 Boot Device
0 Bootloader (BL)
1 Monitor (MO|ML)
2 Exec
5 Application
6 Platform
10 Monitor data
16 Scarchpad
22 Config Block
24 IST (IS)
25 OS (OS)
26 External agent (EA)
27 SuperSpam (SS)
29 Splash screen (SC)
30 Control
32 Partition Table (PT)
```

The commands we can see are

```
 boot     [clean]
 ?        [command]
 h        [command]
 cd       foldername
 cls
 chk      [Partition Number [v]]
 cmp      src dest length
 copy     src dest length
 d        source [dest|p=[#]] [m] [g] [raw] [l=length] [-list]
 dir      filename
 echo     string
 emmc     r | w | e | l | u | p | h | ?
 g        [address][p]
 hk       [c|a]
 info     [ i|p|v|tlb]
 kitl     [l | s | flags x | mac x | ip x | mask x | trans x]
 mac
 man      [ESN [number]] | [BT [BT number]] |
     [MAC [MAC address]] |
     [XWING [count]] | [XWINGID]

 mb       [address [count [value]]]
 md       [address [count [value]]]
 mw       [address [count [value]]]
 menu
 pea      filespec
 pd       address [value]
 pw       address [value]
 pb       address [value]
 r        [register [value]]
 relocate PartNum from|to sector
 reset    [w|warm|c|cold]
 run      [download_source] [v]
 sum      src len
 t
 type     filename
 verify    [full | part | none]
```

The hyperterminal is set to 11500 8-N-1.

Comment: Why the [linux-kernel] tag?

Comment: If it is not your device or your code then your question is almost certainly off-topic on SO and definitely unclear.  It appears that your device is [this](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/release-notes/operating-system/mc9200-operating-system-premium-bsp-04-57-04-update-loader-image-release-notes.html).   In the "Installation Requirements" it states _"MC92N0 terminal must contain released version of CE7.0 Software."_, but it looks like you may have blanked that too - installing the application is insufficient, you need to install WinCE too - that probably requires JTAG.

Comment: https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/request-repair.html

Comment: Perhaps also:  https://supportcommunity.zebra.com/s/article/Steps-to-Factory-Reset-MC92N0-Windows-CE7-0-via-Bootloader?language=en_US it includes a link to teh manual that also has information on the bootloader.  Either way teh manufacturers support pages and forum is where you should start - not here.

Comment: OMAP4430 is the SoC, not an eMMC.

Comment: Yes this is right having done some more research i now understand that the device is lost, it can be returned to the Zebra service center, but cost effective is to purchase a new one.